# Class conversion not working as expected

Tags: c++

I defined simple conversion method

```
operator string() { return /*...*/; }
```

When I call it directly

```
obj.operator string()
```

It works fine, but when I call it this way ...

```
(string)obj
```

Result is empty string.

What's going on? (I'm using gcc c++14) (Can post code If needed)

Class

```
class String : public std::string {
      std::string str_;
    public:
      String() {};
      String(const String & s) {
        str_ = std::string(s.str_);
      };
      String(String && s) {
        str_ = std::string(s.str_);
      };
      String(const string & s) {
        str_ = std::string(s);
      };
      String(const char * s) {
        str_ = std::string(s);
      };

      char & operator[](size_t i) {
        return str_[i];
      };
      String & operator=(const String & str) {
        if (this != &str) {
          str_ = str.str_;
        }
        return *this;
      };
      String & operator=(String && str) {
        if (this != &str) {
          str_ = str.str_;
        }
        return *this;
      };

      bool operator==(const String & str) {
        return str_ == str.str_;
      };
      bool operator!=(const String & str) {
        return str_ != str.str_;
      };

      operator string() {
        return str_;
      };
  };
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Why are you publicly deriving from `std::string` and then using separate member instance? You're slicing, not calling the conversion operator.

Comment: Well, not using c++ for a while, so no idea what you mean

Comment: Compiler warning from clang: "Conversion function converting 'String' to its base class 'std::__1::basic_string<char>' will never be used" is evidence of that. If you get no such warning from your toolchain, perhaps turn up your warning levels. Then decide what you're *really* trying to do, because inheriting from `std::string`, and member-instancing `std::string` seems like two different implementation paths being tried at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your class is deriving from `std::string`.

Remove the `: public std::string` part and the conversion operator will be used.

You class is already declaring an `std::string` member (so it uses the "has-a" approach) and doesn't need the "is-a" approach.

By the way deriving from standard library classes is almost always a bad idea (they were not designed for that).